# Xamarin Forms Push notifications not received properly when the app is closed in android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub

We have configured push notifications in our Xamarin Application for both android and iOS. In iOS notifications are being received properly. But in Android, specifically when the app is closed the notifications are not being received properly.

When the app is open, push notification is triggered and displayed properly as expected, can be observed in the screenshot attached.

When the app is closed, push notification is triggered and displayed as "body", can be observed in the screenshot attached.

Note* Notifications are being sent from ASP.net core with Azure Notifications hub.

The payload looks like below : new JObject(new JProperty("notification", pushMessage)).ToString(Formatting.None);

[Andoid Notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKxr3.jpg)

I tried changing notification payload in different ways but still result didn't change.

Comment: Here is the link to the Azure Notification Hubs [documentation:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/)
Send push notifications to Xamarin.Android apps using Azure Notification Hubs | [Microsoft Docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm.md)
Send push notifications to Xamarin using Azure Notification Hubs | [Microsoft Docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started.md)